# Class "ZipArchive" not found

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to read an Excel file but throws:

> Class "ZipArchive" not found

I have read the [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/collection.html). I have followed the `maatwebsite` documentation installed packages too.

##### My code

```
public function import_excel()
{
    $unitId = Cookie::get('selectedUnit');
    // validation
    $this->validate([
        'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,xls,xlsx'
    ]);

    Excel::import(new ProductImport, $this->file);
    Session::flash('message', 'Product Created Successfully');

    $this->closeModal();
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal');
}
```

I've searched for this solution on StackOverflow, google, and ChatGPT, but none worked.

Comment: `ZipArchive` is part of the [zip extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php). This is in the [requirements](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html)

Comment: as @apokryfos wrote, you literally do not have `php_zip` installed... depending on your server system, check how to install it. For Ubuntu and most linux distros: `sudo apt install php-zip`

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer, here is the answer:

1. Go to Xampp Server config file pannel php.ini.
2. Change the line: ;extension=zip to extension=zip (Just remove the ; before extension=zip).
3. Save php.ini.
4. Restart Xampp Server.

and I used a valet, therefore there is an error message "Class "ZipArchive" not found," the solution has been mentioned above, and you need to use "php artisan serve." Thank you in advance.